# ¿Porque me da error UNMATCHED en el curl?

Tags: servidor, curl, http-post, testing, datarow

Alguien sabe porque me está dando error?

`unmatched brace in URL position 2: '{contact1:`

y

`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Ests es el codigo original:

`curl -i -X POST https://echo-serv.tbxnet.com/v1/test --header "accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{ "contact1": "David "Dave" Letterman", "price": "30.00", "details": "Greatest '''Hits''' Album" }'`

¿Si coloque al final de mi código el símbolo "}"?

debe ser algo que no estoy viendo, agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Tienes un fallo tipográfico en este texto: `"David "Dave" Letterman"`  donde no estás escapando las comillas dobles internas.  Cambia eso por `"David \"Dave\" Letterman"`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo modifique asi y me sigue dando el error.

`curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}'`

`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Comment: Pues a mi, con tan solo cambiar eso, me devuelve todo un churro de cosas así: `{"date":"2022-11-06T15:28:02.348Z","protocol":"https","method":"POST","originalUrl":"/v1/test","query":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{"host":"echo-serv.tbxnet.com","x-request-id":"c94884e70990c55717baa8d0d484e197","x-real-ip":"xx.xxx.xxx.xx","x-forwarded-for":"xx.xxx.xxx.xx","x-forwarded-host":"echo-serv.tbxnet.com","x-forwarded-port":"80","x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-forwarded-scheme":"https","x-scheme":"https","x-original-forwarded-for":"xx.xxx.xxx.xx","content-length":"94","accept-encoding":"gzip",`

Comment: `"cf-ray":"765edb4e0864194a-BCN","cf-visitor":"{\"scheme\":\"https\"}","user-agent":"curl/7.68.0","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","cf-connecting-ip":"xx.xxx.xxx.xx","cf-ipcountry":"ES","cdn-loop":"cloudflare"},"body":{"contact1":"David \"Dave\" Letterman","price":"30.00","details":"Greatest Hits Album"}}`

Comment: es decir, no me da un error, sino una respuesta, que entiendo que es lo que esperas que suceda.  Revisa bien tu instrucción y que sea como en la pregunta para que al aplicar la corrección que he indicado al menos te de mi mismo resultado

Comment: Si correcto. lo corregí así:

`curl -i -X POST https://echo-serv.tbxnet.com/v1/test --header "accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw {"contact1":"David /"Dave"/ Letterman","price":/"30.00"/,"detailss"."Greatest"/"Hits"/"Album"`

y me arroja este error



`{"code":"SYS-ERR","message":"Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1","details":null,"status":400}`

según entiendo ¿es error de sintaxis?

Comment: Cuando usas las barras así: `/` (normales) en lugar de así `\ ` (contrabarras o invertidas) para escapar las comillas lo estas haciendo mal. Eso no es lo que te puse en mi comentario. Y tan solo debes escapar a "Dave", pues esta dentro de otras comillas, el resto no hace falta.

Comment: sí también lo intente así y me da el mismo error

incluso para revisar fui por partes así, ejemplo: 

`curl -i -X POST https://echo-serv.tbxnet.com/v1/test --header "accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw {"contact1":"David \"Dave\" Letterman"`

y me da de nuevo este error. `{"code":"SYS-ERR","message":"Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1","details":null,"status":400}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Letterman`

¿será por el terminal o la versión del curl que uso que me da distinto a usted?

Comment: porque al colocarlo asi: `curl -i -X POST https://echo-serv.tbxnet.com/v1/test --header "accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw {"contact1":"David "Dave" Letterman"` solo me arroja este error

`{"code":"SYS-ERR","message":"Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1","details":null,"status":400}`

Comment: A ver, te pego la linea completa que yo tengo, pues solo me pegas cachos y no se si es que no los estas usando o es para que te quepa mejor en los comentarios.  Esto a mi me funciona: `curl -i -X POST https://echo-serv.tbxnet.com/v1/test --header "accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{ "contact1": "David \"Dave\" Letterman", "price": "30.00", "details": "Greatest '''Hits''' Album" }'`   Copiala y pégala a ver si aun te da error en tu terminal.

Comment: `{"code":"SYS-ERR","message":"Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0","details":null,"status":400}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 30.00,
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}'
 ^`

Comment: me dan todos esos jajaja

Comment: eso desde donde lo estas ejecutando?  es un terminal de linux o es algo distinto?

Comment: terminal de Windows. simbolo de sistema, curl Version 7.83.1

Comment: Bueno, a mi desde mi terminal de linux con Curl Version 7.68.0 no me da ese problema. No uso windows y no dispongo de ningún dispositivo con el para probarlo, lo siento, ahí ya no puedo ayudarte, lo siento. Aún así, prueba triplicando las comillas que rodean a Dave a ver si cuela, de este modo: `curl -i -X POST https://echo-serv.tbxnet.com/v1/test --header "accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{ "contact1": "David """Dave""" Letterman", "price": "30.00", "details": "Greatest '''Hits''' Album" }'`

Comment: @masterguru es mi terminal, ya que probe en otro linux y funciono al toque, muchas gracias por el apoyo y la paciencia.

Comment: Prueba eso de las comillas triples en windows, lo he leido por ahi y quizas te funcione

Comment: Probe y nada, igual sigo buscando a ver porque me da ese error, gracias nuevamente amigo